# configure script for xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, ipad, configure

I'm working on a cross platform project that uses several open source libraries such as zlib.

When configuring for Linux I simply run the ./configure from a shell. On Windows I can do this from a MingWshell, but what do I do when building for OSX and iPad?

My cross platform code is C/C++, and on OSX/iPad, I have a thin Objective C layer.
I use XCode to build my project for OSX and iPad

I tried running ./configure from a Terminal on my Mac, but this fails with this message:

```
chekcking wether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/[...]/zlib'
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

And basically it doesn'tmake sense to run the script from a Terminal, because I'm not going to use gcc to build anyway, but XCode.

So the short version of my question: how do I run an open source configure script, so that it configures the code to build in XCode for both OSX and iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone should find this thread, the answer is to install `Xcode Command Line Tool`. Then run the configure script directly from a shell.